# Question on nef and big divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $L$ is an effective divisor and $H$ is ample (On a smooth 3-fold) such that $L+H$ is nef.

Then show that $L+H$ is big ( $(L+H)^3 > 0$) ?

This was claimed in a paper, without proof. So I assume it should be well-known.
I am not sure if the restriction on dimension is necessary or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed true.  See for example Lemma 2.60 in Kollar-Mori *Birational Geometry of algebraic varieties*.  In particular, it is shown that a Cartier divisor $D$ is big if and only if $mD \sim A + E$ for some ample divisor $A$ and effective divisor $E$.  This is also proven in Corollary 2.2.7 in Lazarsfeld's *Positivity of in Algebraic Geometry I*.

Anyway, they make no assumptions on the dimension or singularities of the ambient variety, you also don't need the nef assumption.

Answer (score 3):

2 basic comments:

1) $L+H$ big is not equivalent to $(L+H)^3>0$

example: $\mathbb P^2$ blown up at a point, $H=$ any ample and $L=mE$ where $E=$exceptional curve and $m\gg 0$.

2) this is the proof (as mentioned above, it can be found in books and it doesn't require $H+L$ nef):

$h^0(X,a(L+H))\ge h^0(X,aH)\ge \frac { a^n}{n!} H^n + \mathcal O (a^{n-1})$

where $n=\dim X$ and $a\gg 0$ (simple consequence of Riemann-Roch and Serre vanishing).

$\Rightarrow L+H $ is big

Comment: But the OP assumes that $D=L+H$ is nef, and in that case bigness is equivalent to $D^3>0$.

Comment: Good comment...